# Does German New Medicine work?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine, cancer

German New Medicine is a medical treatment developed by Ryke Geerd Hamer. Hamer claims [that the cause for every cancer is a "biological-conflict shock"](http://www.newmedicine.ca/overview.php).

> The German New Medicine is a set of findings and principles that solidly bases the nature of disease on universal biological principles and on the interaction between the three levels that make up the organism: the psyche, the brain and the organ. In German New Medicine, diseases have a biological meaning and are not mistakes of nature.
>
> ...
>
> After twenty years of research and therapy with over 31,000 patients, Dr. Hamer finally established firmly, logically and empirically how biological conflict-shock results in a cold cancerous or necrotic phase and how, if the conflict is resolved, the cancerous or necrotic process is reversed to repair the damage and return the individual to health.

Are there any studies about this German New Medicine? Is there any evidence for the biological mechanisms Hamer claims are the cause of cancer?

Comment: Because I'm German, the 'German New' caught my attention. It apparently it is also called 'Germanic New Medicine'. It's a pity that such things still often indicate a Nazi-connection. Looking at the [English Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_New_Medicine) my initials suspicions seem to were correct: '[..] "Germanic" alternative to mainstream clinical medicine which he claims is part of a Jewish conspiracy to decimate non-Jews.'

Comment: Any theory that incredibly simplistic purporting to describe something as complex as a human body is totally implausible on its face.

Comment: "necrotic process is reversed" set big alarm bells ringing for me because necrosis is cellular death and death is inherently irreversible.  Assuming the damage isn't too severe the dead tissue could be completely replaced, but in most cases the damage can't be completely undone and there will be scar tissue and other lesions left behind.

Answer (score 20):

According to this report from the Swiss Study Group for Complementary and Alternative Methods in Cancer which can be read here: http://assets.krebsliga.ch/downloads/01_02_hamer_e_neu.pdf

> After careful study of the literature and other available information, the Study Group for Complementary 
>   and Alternative Methods in Cancer (SCAC) and the Swiss Cancer League (SCL) have found no evidence that 
>   the assertions of Ryke Geerd Hamer are correct, or that the method of cancer treatment which he 
>   propagates is effective. They therefore advise against their use in the treatment of cancer.

The answer appears to be no.

Answer (score 15):

According to this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryke_Geerd_Hamer)

> no case of a cancer cure by Hamer has been published in the medical literature, nor any studies in specialised journals. Reports in his books "lack the additional data that are essential for medical assessment" and the presentations, of his investigations, at medical conferences "are scientifically unconvincing".

and:

> Hamer is charged and convicted in several European countries and is responsible for numerous deaths among his patients.

His explanation of the GNM contains antisemitic ideology.

Comment: Can you please provide a better reference than wikipedia? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have more material than the more than 30 links below the wikipedia article, from which Legion600 is citing the first one. Most of them are in German language, so I guess the Wikipedia article is of better help than just the one PDF for most of our readers, and these sources are easily reachable from there. And the Wikipedia link shows, how easy it is, to find such information yourself (not you, Sklivvz, but you, the anonymous reader).

Comment: Btw.: This post does cite a references to 30  sources.

Comment: Maybe  a follow up skeptic question can be "Near nobody dies of cancer in Israel?" that can suffice to debunk one main Hamer allegation together with "All oncologists in Germany are jewish"

Answer (score -5):

> Are there any studies about this German New Medicine? 
>   Is there any evidence for the biological mechanisms Hamer 
>   claims are the cause of cancer?

According to this [list of verifications](http://learninggnm.com/SBS/documents/verifications.html#Examples) the answer to the 1st question is YES!

As to the 2nd question, I would argue that the answer is also YES, at list empirically. According to Hamer's findings, a conflict shock manifests it self in the three levels of the psyche, brain and biological organ (as a meaningful growth of cells that may be identified as a tumor). 
Hamer was able to determine the patient's past and present conditions by only looking at the patient's brain CTs, and then verify the conflicts (psyche) by questioning the the patient as to his or her life experience. According to these verifications he had full success. This may support his assertion that cancer is a meaningful reaction of the body to an evolutionary meaningful conflict shock.

Comment: This is just more evidence that the original claimant believes his claim. These do not look like peer reviewed scientific findings. Why should I believe that these are correct?

Comment: Even nematode worms get cancers: not a lot of psyche and brains present to be affected by their "life experiences"

Comment: And [plants can develop tumours](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7457/can-plants-get-cancer). Would like to see how questioning a tree about its psyche and life experience would help.